# 3G connection not working from Android emulator 2.2

Tags: android-emulator, 3g

Am Using Android emulator 2.2. 3G connection not working from emulator 2.2 and sometimes working in 1.6. my friends are working with these two emulator in their systems fine. What is the problem. Why it is not connected for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of emulator `com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService` failed. Due to this 3g is not working. And once i restart the emulator it works fine and i didnt receive com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService failed message.